# Create a list of int using LINQ from cell collections

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview, group-by

I have a collection of selected cells. As there are multiple columns, the row indices of the cells in the collection usually come in a format like 2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4 etc.

I'd like to get a list of row indices of these cells.

```
List<int> selectedRows = new List<int>();

List<DataGridViewCell> cellCollection = dGV_model.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                                      .GroupBy(cell => cell.RowIndex)
                                      .Select(cell => cell.First())
                                      .ToList<DataGridViewCell>();
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in cellCollection)
{
    selectedRows.Add(cell.RowIndex);
}
```

Essentially, my question is how do I create a List of int from a single LINQ query? Right now, I have to iterate through the cellcollection to add them into a List of int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var selectedRows = dGV_model.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                                          .Select(c=>c.RowIndex).Distinct()
                                          .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
var rows = dGV_model.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
                            .Select(x=>x.RowIndex).Distinct()
                            .ToList();
```